# Trying to prevent non admins from signing up for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a simple blog and I only want admin access to the create admin options and view. I have installed Devise and used authenticate_admin! in my controllers but when I test it out, the page is still accessible and allows anyone to sign out for admin options. I have limited options to the admin once signed in. The problem is that anyone can sign in. If I can basically just prevent access to the admin sign up page then I'm golden. At least in this case. I'm curious if somebody can point out my error or errors. Let me know if you need anything else. Thanks

```
class AdminsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!



  def index
  end

  def created
  end
end
```

Articles Controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!, :except => [:index, :show]




  def new
    @article = Article.new
  end

  def index
    @article = Article.all


    @articles = Article.order('created_at DESC')
    @articles_by_month = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |article| article.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end


  def month_count
    @articles_by_month = Article.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC').group_by { |article| article.created_at.strftime("%B %Y") }
  end

  def create  
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

      if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end



  def edit
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])

    if @article.update(article_params)
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy

    redirect_to articles_path
  end

  private

  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :image)
  end

end
```

Articles Index view

```
<div class="bit-75">

  <% @article.each do |article| %>
    <h2 id="title"><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></h2>
    <br>
    <ul id="article-links">
      <div id="article-image"><%= image_tag article.image_url %></div>
      <br>
      <li id="article-text"><%= article.text %></li>
    <p>Posted on <%= article.created_at %></p>
    <br>


    <% if admin_signed_in? %>
      <li><%= link_to 'Edit',           edit_article_path(article) %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'Destroy',        article_path(article),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></li>
      <li><%= link_to 'New article', new_article_path %></li>
    <% else %>                
      <li><%= link_to 'Make a Comment', article_path(article) %><p>Comments(<%= article.comments.count %>)</p></li>      
    </ul>
    <% end %>   
  <% end %>

<div id="new-article-path"></div>
</div>
<div class="bit-5">
  <h2>Recent Posts</h2>

    <br>

  <% @article.each do |article| %>

    <ul id="recent-article">
      <li><%= link_to article.title, article_path(article) %></li>
    </ul>

  <% end %>
    <br>
    <br>

  <h2>Archives</h2>

  <% @articles_by_month.each do |monthname, articles| %>
    <h4 id="month-archive"><%=link_to monthname, archives_path %></h4>

    <% end %>



  <!-- <h2>Tags</h2> -->
</div>
```

Admin model

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Article Model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 5 }
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader 
  default_scope -> { order('created_at DESC') }                 
end
```

Routes

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins

  devise_scope :admin do get "/admins/sign_out", to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  devise_scope :admin do
    get "/admins/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  devise_for :users
  root 'articles#index'

  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end


  get "welcome/index"



  match '/about',     to: 'static_pages#about',     via: 'get'
  match '/contact',   to: 'static_pages#contact',   via: 'get'
  match '/archives',  to: 'archives#index',         via: 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove `registerable` in your Admin model to prevent people from signing up as an admin:

`devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable`

but having devise_for `:admins` and then `:users` hints that it may be time for you to look into using a permission management gem like [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Comment: I'll give it a try. I thought about Can Can but didn't want to use it if possible. I'll see what works and let you know. THanks. Sorry for the late response. Haven't been able to get back on here for a few days.

Comment: That worked tirdadc. Thanks. Will look into Can Can to maybe streamline things better.